# null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.List - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

I'm trying to add search Filterable in RecyclerView. but the app is getting crashed with following error:

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
>   kotlin.collections.List
>                   at com.kabelash.movies.ui.PostListAdapter$searchFilter$1.publishResults(PostListAdapter.kt:87)
>                   at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:284)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)

Adapter:

```
class PostListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PostListAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private lateinit var postListFiltered:List<Data>
    private lateinit var postListFull:List<Data>

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding: ListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(postListFiltered[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if(::postListFiltered.isInitialized) postListFiltered.size else 0
    }

    fun updatePostList(postList:List<Data>){
        this.postListFiltered = postList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: ListItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private val viewModel = MoviesViewModel()

        fun bind(post:Data){
            viewModel.bind(post)
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
        }

    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter? {
        return searchFilter
    }

    private val searchFilter: Filter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults? {
            val filteredList: MutableList<Data> = ArrayList()
            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(postListFull)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
                for (item in postListFull) {
                    if (item.title.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) || item.genre.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item)
                    }
                }

            }
            val results = FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?,results: FilterResults) {
            postListFiltered = (results.values as List<Data>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any other class file please do let me know. Can someone please help me to solve it?

Comment: It looks like result.values is null in your `postListFiltered = (results.values as List<Data>)` - that' the reason of your crash. `postListFiltered` is non nullable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: None of the answers so far are explaining how it's possible for `results.values` to be null. The Filter implementation very clearly always assigns it a non-nullable. You should be able to avoid the immediate error with `postListFiltered = (results.values as List<Data>?).orEmpty()`, but this is probably masking some other bug that you'll still have to solve.

Comment: Does your log include an warning with tag "Filter" and message "An exception occured during performFiltering()!" ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 i understand that it's not the same exception or cause. but OP is trying to cast a null to something which isn't expecting null, this post provides various different reasons as to 1)why something can be null and 2) how to handle things being null, figured it would be useful and relevant to OP seeing as though the stack trace already points them towards the right direction

Comment: @Tenfour04 postListFiltered = (results.values as List<Data>?).orEmpty() is actually an answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's this line:
`results.values as List<Data>`

`results.values` is null, and you're telling it to be a non-null list, which it can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform a null check before performing the cast, modify your pulishResults method as following.

```
   override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?,results: FilterResults) {
                postListFiltered = if(results == null || results.values == null)
                                       ArrayList<Data>() 
                                   else
                                        results.values
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other two answers correctly point out, your `results.values` is null.  But the code clearly shows that the FilterResults returned from `performFiltering` always has a non-null `values` field.  How can this have happened?

A brief look at the `Filter` source code gives a possible answer:

```
// Filter.RequestHandler.handleMessage(Message msg)

try {
    args.results = performFiltering(args.constraint);
} catch (Exception e) {
    args.results = new FilterResults();
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "An exception occured during performFiltering()!", e);
}
```

In plain English, if `performFiltering()` throws an exception, the filter catches the exception and uses an empty FilterResults in place of what would otherwise be returned.  The stack trace for this exception can be found in logcat.

Looking at your `performFiltering` function, the only exception that stands out is `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.  If this turns out to be the exception thrown, you can fix it by either checking whether the `fullPostList` property is initialized or explicitly initializing it to the empty list.